# TensorFlow XOR NN eval function error

Tags: python, tensorflow, runtime-error, eval, invalid-argument

I'm trying to write a XOR MLP using vanilla tensorflow and am stuck trying to figure out how to write the eval function.

I'm getting the error `InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): targets[1] is out of range`. When commenting out the `accuracy.eval` line no errors are produced. Here's my code:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

n_inputs = 2
n_hidden = 3
n_outputs = 1

def reset_graph(seed=42):
    tf.reset_default_graph()
    tf.set_random_seed(seed)
    np.random.seed(seed)

reset_graph()

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, n_inputs), name='X')
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None), name='y')

def neuron_layer(X, n_neurons, name, activation=None):
    with tf.name_scope(name):
        n_inputs = int(X.get_shape()[1])
        stddev = 2 / np.sqrt(n_inputs)
        init = tf.truncated_normal((n_inputs, n_neurons), stddev=stddev)
        W = tf.Variable(init, name="weights")
        b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([n_neurons]), name="bias")
        Z = tf.matmul(X, W) + b
        if activation is not None:
            return activation(Z)
        else: return Z

with tf.name_scope('dnn'):
    hidden = neuron_layer(X, n_hidden, name='hidden', activation=tf.nn.sigmoid)
    logits = neuron_layer(hidden, n_outputs, name='outputs')

with tf.name_scope('loss'):
    bin_xentropy = tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y, logits=logits)
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(bin_xentropy, name='loss')    

learning_rate = 0.1

with tf.name_scope('train'):
    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate)
    training_op = optimizer.minimize(loss)

with tf.name_scope('eval'):    
    correct = tf.nn.in_top_k(logits, tf.cast(y,tf.int32), 1)
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, tf.float32))
    accuracy_summary = tf.summary.scalar('accuracy', accuracy)


init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
saver = tf.train.Saver()

n_epochs = 100
batch_size = 4

def shuffle_batch(X, y, batch_size): # not really needed for XOR
    rnd_idx = np.random.permutation(len(X))
    n_batches = len(X) // batch_size
    for batch_idx in np.array_split(rnd_idx, n_batches):
        X_batch, y_batch = X[batch_idx], y[batch_idx]
        yield X_batch, y_batch

X_train = [
    (0, 0),
    (0, 1),
    (1, 0),
    (1, 1)
]
y_train = [0,1,1,0]    

X_train = np.array(X_train)
y_train = np.array(y_train)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    init.run()
    for epoch in range(n_epochs):
        for X_batch, y_batch in shuffle_batch(X_train, y_train, batch_size):
            sess.run(training_op, feed_dict={X: X_batch, y: y_batch})        
        acc = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={X: X_train, y: y_train})
        print(acc)
```

Could someone show me what I'm doing wrong with this function? I tried adapting XOR from the MNIST example in the Hands-On Machine Learning book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really clear what you're trying to achieve with

`correct = tf.nn.in_top_k(logits, tf.cast(y,tf.int32), 1)`

I'd recommend using

`correct = tf.equal(
    tf.reshape(
        tf.greater_equal(tf.nn.sigmoid(logits),0.5),[-1]
    ), 
    tf.cast(y,tf.bool)
)`

**Edited**: I noticed that the accuracy is stuck at 0.5 in the given solution. I was able to get this solution to work (accuracy: 100.0) by making the following changes.

Changed the network to the following. (using tanh, using two hidden layers)

`with tf.name_scope('dnn'):
    hidden1 = neuron_layer(X, n_hidden, name='hidden1', activation=tf.nn.tanh)
    hidden2 = neuron_layer(hidden1, n_hidden, name='hidden2', activation=tf.nn.tanh)
    logits = neuron_layer(hidden2, n_outputs, name='outputs')`

and `n_hidden = 7` , `n_epochs = 5`

**Note**: I'm not really sure why it needs two hidden layers. But apparently it needs to to get it to work in this settings.

Comment: Hmm thanks, that makes more sense, only it seems like something is reversed because it's getting worse instead of better.

Comment: I edited my solution with another finding. Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks! I found from another question that I also should have made the target labels a list of lists. Maybe that it part (or all) of the issue.